# How to pass connection between API route in Rocket framework?

Tags: rust, odbc, rust-rocket

I have successfully establish database connection using ODBC in Rust, specifically using odbc-api. How to pass around the connection in API routes in Rocket framework? I know the idea will include state. Anyone can suggest the exact flow?

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation](https://rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/guide/state/)?

Comment: Why do you want to pass around the connection? Connection Pooling?